# HttpClient - Connection closed in VSTO and not in console

Tags: c#, httpclient, vsto

I have the same piece of code that I would like to execute from two different places.

The code :

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "...");
var post = client.PostAsync("https://mycompany.com/...", new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
var str = post.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

When putting this code in a console it works fine and I have the expected result (a Json in `str`).

However when putting it in an Outlook VSTO project (in the Ribbon part). It fails systematically telling me that the connection was already closed :

`The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly`

In VSTO, I tried:

- Using a GetStringAsync() with no Authorization header without success
- Adding `client.CancelPendingRequests();` without success

In the other hand, when asking for another website content, it works (ie: I changed http://mycompany.com to https://google.com).

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had similar problem with `HttpClient` in the Outlook VSTO and I added

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

that helped me to resolve the issue.

Probably try playing with `SecurityProtocol`.